# Are 'gmailified' inboxes accessible via the gmail API?

Tags: gmail-api

Google just released Gmailify yesterday:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/gmailify-best-of-gmail-without-gmail.html

If one Gmailifies a third-party email address, can data from that email address then be accessed via the Gmail API?

If not, is this coming? And/or if so, are there any quirks we should be aware of?

Comment: Reading [this support answer](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6304825) it looks like reading mail, responding to mail with the linked email etc. should propagate it to the original provider. Very interesting! Should not be that hard do test :)